# display product name in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

[image: in that product name column I want to display product name]

I want to display product name in that column

Comment: product name in your database table or not?

Comment: no i have entity_id through that i want to display product name using join query

Comment: Are you using UI component?

Comment: yes UI component through that product name column is coming

Comment: You can please provide me  Dataprovider class

Answer (score 0):

***You have to create a Collection Class which is replicated of current collection class.***

Then you have to use a new collection class as the data provider class for ui listing.

Then on protected function _initSelect() of collection, you need to add `catalog_product_entity_varchar`  table list

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
 */
private $productAttributeRepository;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository      
) {

    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
}
private function getAttributeId(){
    $attribute = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('name');
    return $attribute->getAttributeId();
}
protected function _joinFields()
{
    $nameTable = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar');

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('cpev' => $nameTable), 
        'cpev.entity_id=prod.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id='.$this->getAttributeId().'', 
        array('name' => 'value')
    );
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: where I have to put this code please provide a folder structure

Comment: Please giev data provide code which maintain at `dataProvider class="` at ui xml file

Comment: <column name="name">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
     <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">product name</item>
     <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
      </item>
     </item>
    </item>
   </argument>
  </column>

Comment: NO. there will be some tag like` <dataProvider>`.I need   tag s code

Comment: in which file it is written

Comment: the same file from you have  copied above xml code

Comment: in that there is no such code

Comment: in above code cpev is table name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89718/discussion-between-ashish-ramchandani-and-amit-bera).